# Insert CSV entries into database in batches

Tags: python, csv

Requirement : Read all the CSV files under /root folder and with the batch of 2 rows with delay of 10sec insert the data into DB. For which developed below script.

CSV files in /root folder
#cat f1.csv
Bob,Nsk,India
Rob,Nsk,India
Mat,Nsk,India
Nick,Nsk,India
Dev,Nsk,India
San,Nsk,India

#cat f2.csv
AB,Pune,India
CD,Pune,India
EF,Pune,India
GH,Pune,India
IJ,Pune,India
KL,Pune,India
MN,Pune,India

```
import psycopg2
import glob
import time
# Import and Read the CSVs

csv_files = glob.glob('/root/*.csv')
skip=0
while True:
  for file in csv_files:
        df = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=skip, header=None, nrows=2)
        print(df)
  skip+=2
  time.sleep(10)
  #Connect to DB
  conn = psycopg2.connect(database="test", user='postgres', password='***', host='***', port= '5432')

  # create a cursor
  cursor = conn.cursor()

  #Insert data from CSV to DB
  for i, row in df.iterrows():
              #here %S means string values
               sql = "INSERT INTO student(name, city, country) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
               cursor.execute(sql, tuple(row))

  # Commit your changes in the database
  conn.commit()
  print("Records inserted........")

  #Closing the connection
  conn.close()
```

By running this script it just inserting f2.csv entries. What I am missing so it should insert f1.csv entries as well ?

```
test=> select * from student;
 name | city | country
------+------+---------
 AB   | Pune | India
 CD   | Pune | India
 EF   | Pune | India
 GH   | Pune | India
 IJ   | Pune | India
 KL   | Pune | India
(6 rows)
```

Comment: It appears your code is missing one indentation starting from `skip+=2`. Thus all the code from `skip+=2` to `conn.close()` is only performed on the last csv file from the `for file in csv_files:` loop. As a side note, you should also use a consistent number of spaces for indentation.